# Jquery Datatables 1.10 search function only works once

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to perform a search on a datatable when a user clicks a search button.

If I click the NY/London button, the table will filter correctly. 
If I now click the San Francisco button, the table will show no records.

I assume this behaviour is because the table needs to be cleared of all existing searches before a new one can be done. I can't figure out how to do that.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  function filter_table(param1,param2){
     $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
             function( settings, data, dataIndex ) { 
               if ( data[2]==param1 || data[2]==param2){return true;}
               return false;
             }
        ); 
  }


  $("#ny_london").click(function(){
    filter_table('New York','London');
    table.draw();
  });


  $("#sf").click(function(){
    filter_table('San Francisco',null);
    table.draw();
  });

} );
```

Here's a live link to the table and code.

http://live.datatables.net/tulavila/1/edit

Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: It is not the case that NY/London button works and the San Francisco button does not. If you click San Francisco button first then you will find out that NY/London button does not perform the way you want it to. This is because the filtered table is redrawn as a new table, which Either San Francisco or NY/London cannot co-exist at the same time.

Comment: So I would need to re-draw the full table first, and then filter. I'm using the datatables filter function in a different way now by just returning true if a row meets my conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adding additional filters each time you click one of the buttons but never removing the old ones. All you really need is a couple of global variables that you change before redrawing the table on each click. The filter is automatically applied to each redraw once it has been pushed to the `search` array.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var param1, param2;

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
       function( settings, data, dataIndex ) { 
           if ( data[2]==param1 || data[2]==param2){return true;}
           return false;
       }
  ); 

  $("#ny_london").click(function(){
    param1 = 'New York';
    param2 = 'London';
    table.draw();
  });

  $("#sf").click(function(){
    param1 = 'San Francisco';
    param2 = '';
    table.draw();
  });
} );
```